# Copy delta data from AWS S3 to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 failed

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake

I am trying to copy files from s3 bucket to blob storage using azure data factory with the "Copy delta data from AWS S3 to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2" template.But it throwing 2 errors during validation.

Validation snapshots are attached here 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true issue is that the sink dataset is missing a parameter in container.open the sink dataset “Azure_Storage_Destination_Store” which created by the template, and input below parameter “@dataset().Azure_Storage_fileSystem” in the Container field. Then the validation error should be resolved.